# Wordpress display readme page instead of home page. Other page and wp-admin are working

Tags: wordpress, html

I have this problem, when i try to get the home page of my wordpress installation, wordpress displays the readme page. The other page are all workings, also `wp-admin`. I checked database, checked correct URL in `wp-option`, checked `wp-config.php`, checked the `.htaccess` file. I also disabled plugins and changed theme. I don't know what to do again to solve this situation. i updated to 4.0.1 version.

Comment: In the backend, when you go to appearance -> Customize, what is listed under the section that asks what page should be displayed for the homepage? Is that page using a custom template?

Also, you should probably share your .htaccess with us, as well as the code for index.php in your root folder.

Comment: Yes, in the apparence is set "home" as a home page, that is a page created. No i'm not using a custom template, i'm using a template from themeforest.

Comment: When you edit the homepage, what is listed under "template" on the right?

Also, I would definitely suggest sharing the contents of the .htaccess file with us.

Answer (score 0):

Inside Wordpress administration go to:

Settings -> Reading -> "Front page displays" -> "A static page" ->and choose the page you want to see there, in your case, something related with Home (Some pages are added by the Theme, so you should have the required theme activated).

Comment: This is one of the first things i did for check. Home page is set as front page display. Thank you.

Comment: if you say that changing theme doesn't help, re-install wordpress, certify the original theme works, then import your old database, then apply your original theme